# Family of transformations can I find a density function?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, transformation, log-likelihood

Let's consider the family of transformations given by
$$g_a(Y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{e^{aY}-1}{a} & \text{ for } a\neq 0 \\
Y & \text{ for } a=0 
\end{cases}$$
for $Y\in\mathbb{R}$. Analogous to the estimation of the Box-Cox parameter $\lambda$, the parameter $a\in\mathbb{R}$ can be estimated using a profile likelihood approach. Let $Y_1,...,Y_n\in\mathbb{R}$ be independent
responses together with corresponding predictors $\mathbf{x}_1,...,\mathbf{x}_n\in\mathbb{R}^n$. We assume for $a$ that there exist $\textbf{b}\in\mathbb{R}^p$ and $\sigma^2>0$ such that $g_a(Y_i)\sim N(\textbf{x}_i^T \textbf{b},\sigma^2)$ for $i=1,...,n$.

Here is my questions:

1. Can we derive such a density function $f_Y$ of the untransformed observations $Y_i$. If so, would it be
   $$f_{Y_i}(\textbf{x})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{(\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_i^T\textbf{b})^2}{\sigma^2}}$$
2. How would we find the log-likelihood function $\ell(a,b,\sigma^2;y_1,...,y_n)$? I know that $\sum_{i=1}^n \log(f_{Y_i}(y_i))$.

Thanks in advance.